# EditPad: How to replace multiple search criteria with multiple values?

Tags: regex, replace, editpad

I did some searching and found tons of questions about multiple replacements with Regex, but I'm working in EditPadPro and so need a solution that works with the regex syntax of that environment.  Hoping someone has some pointers as I haven't been able to work out the solution on my own.

Additional disclaimer:  I suck with regex.  I mean really... it's bad.  Like I barely know wtf I'm doing.So that being said, here is what I need to do and how I'm currently approaching it...

I need to replace two possible values, with their corresponding replacements.  My two searches are:

`(.*)-sm`
`(.*)-rad`

Currently I run these separately and replace each with simple strings:

`sm`
`rad`

Basically I need to lop off anything that comes prior to "sm" so I just detect everything up to and including sm, and then replace it all with that string (and likewise for "rad").

But it seems like there should be a way to do this in a single search/replace operation.  I can do the search part fine with:

`(.*)-sm|(.*)-rad`

But then how to replace each with it's matching value?  That's where I'm stuck.  I tried:

`sm|rad`

but alas, that just becomes the literal complete string that is used for replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
(.*)-(sm|rad)
```

Now, when you put something in parenthesis in Regex, those matches are stored in temporary variables.  So whatever matched (.*) is stored in **\1** and whatever matched (sm|rad) is stored in **\2**.  Therefore, you want to replace with:

```
\2
```

Note that the replacement variable may be different depending on what programming language you are using.  In Perl, for example, I would have to use **$2** instead.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, which I am now editing.  Thanks for this, it works great!

Comment: I apologize, I misread the times of the answers given, this one was actually given first so I am awarding it correct answer.  Sorry again for any confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan, first off let me congratulate you for using EPP Pro for regex in your text. It's my main text editor, and the main reason I chose it, as a regex lover, is that its support of regex syntax is vastly superior to competing editors. For instance Notepad++ is known for its shoddy support of regular expressions. The reason of course is that EPP's author Jan Goyvaerts is the author of the legendary RegexBuddy.

A picture is worth a thousand words... So here is how I would do your replacement. Just hit the "replace all button". The expression in the regex box assumes that anything before the dash that is not a whitespace character can be stripped, so if this is not what you want, we need to tune it.

[image: EPP regex screenshot]

Comment: This solution works perfectly and since it was given first, I will award it as the correct answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I apologize, I misread the times of the answers given, this one was actually given second so I am awarding correct answer to the first response.  Sorry again for any confusion!